# Retrieve child just when value change firebase vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an my first application with Vue and Firebase.

In one page you can create a post and you send to real time database *name email picture and status.*

In another page (the admin one) you decide if that post will be published or not changing status to true or false. 
So:

```
 reading() {
            this.postRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
                this.posts.push(snapshot.val());
                this.key.push(snapshot.key);
            }), 
changeStatus(index) {
            let key = this.key[index]
            this.posts[index].status = true;
            firebase.database().ref('posts/'+ key +'/status').set('true')
        },
```

Once the status is true, posts have to be visible in the wall page.

How can I retrieve just the child that have status == true in real time in the **wall page**?
Right now I'm using this method:

```
 reading() {
            this.postRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
                this.posts.push(snapshot.val());
                this.key.push(snapshot.key);
            })
```

And in the template:

```
 <v-layout row wrap justify-center v-for="(item, index) in posts">
```

I've tried with v-if="item.status == true" but I need to refresh the page all the time to see the new posts.

Here my DB

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `on()` method to observe events in the **entire** `postRef` node, you should filter the data, as explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data

So you could do something like the following, in order to filter data and to only listen to events that correspond to a change from `status == false` to `status == true`:

```
reading() {
            this.postRef.orderByChild('status').equalTo(true).on('child_added', snapshot => {
                this.posts.push(snapshot.val());
                this.key.push(snapshot.key);
            })
```